# What's the correct regex to use for parsing data from a webpage source between tags?

Tags: java, regex

Hi I'm having some trouble with parsing some data from a web source between two "tags"

Here's what a sample of the web source and the code I'm using to try and parse it.

```
 <div class="ProfileTweet-contents">

      <p class="ProfileTweet-text js-tweet-text u-dir"

        dir="ltr">Come join us now! <a href="http://t.co/Kbhh2ed" rel="nofollow" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://forum.epicurus-pk.com/" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://www.google.com" ><span class="tco-ellipsis"></span><span class="invisible">http://</span><span class="js-display-url">www.google.com</span><span class="invisible">/</span><span class="tco-ellipsis"><span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span></span></a> <a href="http://t.co/jIw2344dDZz" class="twitter-timeline-link u-isHiddenVisually" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >pic.twitter.com/jIwtc23juZz</a></p>
```

Code

```
   while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("dir=.?!<a href=");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            tweets[0] = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
```

The item of data I'm trying to fetch is the following

```
dir="ltr">Come join us now! <a href=
```

For some reason it's not fetching the data inbetween dir= and < a href

Another working example which is parsing the web source just fine

```
  URL addr = new URL(url);
      URLConnection con = addr.openConnection();
      ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<span itemprop=.*?</span>");
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(">.*?<");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(inputLine);
            Matcher m2;
            while (m.find()) {
                m2 = p2.matcher(m.group());
                while (m2.find()) {
                    data.add(m2.group().replaceAll("<", "").replaceAll(">", "").replaceAll("&", "").replaceAll("#", "").replaceAll(";", "").replaceAll("3",""));
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
        addr = null;
        con = null;
```

Edit: Sorry have just realised I was using a different regex from my other code example without realising.

```
(dir=).*?(<a href=)
```

Works fine

Comment: Instead of using regex, why not try [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?

Comment: It's for learning purposes

Comment: In that case you need to add space in your regex between `!` and `<a`. (your regex contains `!<a href=` but your data is `! <a href=`). But seriously, don't use regex to parse XML in real world.

Comment: @Kieran: Try this: `=\\s*"ltr"[^>]*>([^<]+)<a\\s*a`.

Comment: I'm able to do it with another website without problems, please review OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for a pattern such as:

```
(dir=\".+\">.+<a\\shref=).+rel
```

The reason your original pattern doesn't work is that you've not included several characters in your pattern such as `"` along with improperly using `.?` — it's not going capture anything between that and `!`.

Here a working example of the pattern above:

**http://ideone.com/wbH9O6**

Answer (score 0):

Use a XML parser is the short version of the answer. If the html is mangled use a HTML parser that will try to make sense of the madness . Read this post as a bonus :

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)